# Chrome extension doesn't work on Ubuntu. Dictionary.com

Tags: 13.10, google-chrome, chrome-extension

I had [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dictionary-by-dictionaryc/gikhgcaliglmioibbockkmjknfnepbdh?hl=en) extension when I was using chrome on windows. When I switched to Ubuntu all extensions and apps synced automatically except this one.

When I opened the chrome web store and went to this extension it says that I have it installed. I tried to uninstall and resinstall it but it doesn't appear. It's there on windows!

What's wrong? How is this possible? This extension is my life saver. I really don't like using google's dictionary although I've been using it for quite a while.